# Filter specific properties and sum the values

Tags: javascript, filter, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map with polygons, you can click on each polygon to select them and there is an info window "L.control" that shows the values for the selected polygon. As you continue click on polygons the info window add values for each selected and you get total values for all selected polygons. All this is fine but I need to get down to more detailed sum for specific properties like the example below of regions. If ten polygons are selected I want to differentiate the total amount for regions with properties "REGION SOUTH" and "REGION NORTH" as well as the total of all.
This is the code I'm using, to sum the totals of different properties is no problem but how do you sum for defined properties?

How and where can I add a kind of filter solution that sum only the properties I want?

```
$.each(statesData.features, function(index, feature) {
var name = `${feature.properties.ZIPCODE} ${feature.properties.Name}  ( ${feature.properties.average_time} -  ${feature.properties.CITY})`
placenames.push(name);
zipcodes[name] = feature.properties.ZIPCODE;
time = feature.properties.average_time
});

etc.... 

// Now get the totals of selected polygons
var detailshow = function() {
var result = ''
var total = 0
var total1 = 0
var total2 = 0
var total3 = 0
var total4 = 0
for (var i = 0; i < featuresSelected.length; i++) {

var properties = featuresSelected[i].feature.properties
    result +=
        `
    ${properties.CITY}<br>
    Zipcode: ${properties.ZIPCODE}
    <a href="#" onclick=dellayer(${properties.ZIPCODE})>Delete</a>
    <hr>`;
    total += properties.amount, // sum amount for all regions
    total1 += properties.average_time, // in seconds
    total2 += properties.distance,
    total3 += properties.amount, // amount for Region South only
    total4 += properties.amount, // amount for Region North only

    // Convert seconds to timeformat
    var convertTime = function (input, separator) {
    var pad = function(input) {return input < 10 ? "0" + input : input;};
        return [
        pad(Math.floor(input / 3600)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 3600 / 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 60)),
        ].join(typeof separator !== 'undefined' ?  separator : ':' );
    }

var resultTime = convertTime(total1);

}
return {
    result: result,
    total: total,
    resultTime: resultTime,
    total2: total2
    total3: total3
    total4: total4
};
}

detailsselected.update = function(arrayselected) {

var details = detailshow()
this._div.innerHTML =
'<b>Zipcodes</b><br>' + 
'Total time: <b>' + details.resultTime + ' hh:mm:ss</b><br>' +
'Total amount: <b>' + details.total + ' st</b><br>' +
'Region South amount: <b>' + details.total3 + ' st</b><br>' +
'Region North amount: <b>' + details.total4 + ' st</b><br>' +
'Distance: <b>' + details.total2.toFixed(1) + ' km</b><br>';
$('#suma', window.parent.document).val(details.resultTime, details.total, details.total2, details.total3, details.total4);


};

detailsselected.addTo(map);
```

FeatureSelected:

```
function checkExistsLayers(feature) {
var result = false
for (var i = 0; i < featuresSelected.length; i++) {
    if (featuresSelected[i].ZIPCODE == feature.properties.ZIPCODE) {
        result = true;
        break;
    }
};
return result
```

}

This is part of the json file structure:

```
var statesData = new L.LayerGroup;
var statesData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ZIPCODE":12345,"CITY":"LONDON","REGION":"REGION SOUTH","amount":1088,"average_time":26150,"distance":2.2},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":...
```

I did try the following but that did not work...

```
    function filt_north (feature){
        if (feature.properties.REGION === 'REGION NORTH' )
        return true;
    }

    total4 += filt_north.(properties.amount), // amount for Region North only
```

Comment: What does `featuresSelected[0]` look like?

Comment: Added that part as well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `filt_north` function you wrote looks good, just add a `filt_south` filter to get the south region and do:

```
let filteredResults = featuresSelected.filter(
   result => filt_north(result.feature) || filt_south(result.feature)
);

for (let result of filteredResults) {
    var properties = result.feature.properties;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried your solution, seems it breaks the code and totals is not added up at all = stopped working. I did this, should it be done in a different way?
Filter function:

```
    function filt_south (feature){
    if (feature.properties.REGION === 'REGION SOUTH')
    return true;
}

function filt_north (feature){
    if (feature.properties.REGION === 'REGION NORTH')
    return true;
}
```

Then changed to this (I must be doing something wrong here):

```
    // Now get the totals of selected polygons
    var detailshow = function() {
    var result = ''
    var total = 0
    var total1 = 0
    var total2 = 0
    var total3 = 0
    var total4 = 0

    let filteredResults = featuresSelected.filter(
        result => filt_south(result.feature) || filt_north(result.feature)
        );

    for (let result of filteredResults) {
        var properties = result.feature.properties;

    for (var i = 0; i < featuresSelected.length; i++) { 
        var properties = featuresSelected[i].feature.properties
        result +=
        `
    ${properties.CITY}<br>
    Zipcode: ${properties.ZIPCODE}
    <a href="#" onclick=dellayer(${properties.ZIPCODE})>Delete</a>
    <hr>`;
    total += properties.amount, // sum amount for all regions
    total1 += properties.average_time,
    total2 += properties.distance,
    total3 += filt_south (properties.amount), // amount for Region South only
    total4 += filt_north (properties.amount) // amount for Region North only

    // Convert seconds to timeformat
    var convertTime = function (input, separator) {
    var pad = function(input) {return input < 10 ? "0" + input : input;};
        return [
        pad(Math.floor(input / 3600)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 3600 / 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 60)),
        ].join(typeof separator !== 'undefined' ?  separator : ':' );
    }

var resultTime = convertTime(total1);
}
}
return {
    result: result,
    total: total,
    resultTime: resultTime,
    total2: total2
    total3: total3
    total4: total4
};
}

detailsselected.update = function(arrayselected) {

var details = detailshow()
this._div.innerHTML =
'<b>Zipcodes</b><br>' + 
'Total time: <b>' + details.resultTime + ' hh:mm:ss</b><br>' +
'Total amount: <b>' + details.total + ' st</b><br>' +
'Region South amount: <b>' + details.total3 + ' st</b><br>' +
'Region North amount: <b>' + details.total4 + ' st</b><br>' +
'Distance: <b>' + details.total2.toFixed(1) + ' km</b><br>';
$('#suma', window.parent.document).val(details.resultTime, details.total, details.total2, details.total3, details.total4);


};

detailsselected.addTo(map)
```